# HBase Group by time stamp and count

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hbase

I would like to scan the entire Hbase table and get the count of the number of records added on a particular day on daily basis.
Since we do not have multiple versions of the columns, I can use the time stamp of the latest version(which will always be one).

One approach is to use map reduce. Where map scans all the rows, and we emit timestamp(actual date) and 1 as key and value. Then the reducer, I would count based on timestamp value. Approach is similar to group count based on timestamp.

Is there a better way of doing this? Once implemented, this job would be run on a daily basis, to verify the counts with other modules(Hive table row count and solr document count). I use this, as the starting point to identify any errors, during flow at different integration points in application.

Comment: What is the structure of your key? can you put sample lines and table structure?

Comment: The table have a key(salt_docId). We havn't added date features there, as we are depending on solr for date grouping and others. This requirement is exclusively to get counts at Hbase